# Posting status on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, status

I have created a facebook application.

It's working only for my account means i can send message on my account only.

How it will be possible that users inputs their access_token and message and that
will be authenticated via that access_token and message should be 
sent on that particular user's account through my facebook application.

In sort I want to post status on facebook using only access_token of a user.

I have done same for Twitter and that is working fine.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where's the problem - that other users can't log in, or that they can't post status when they do log in? Is your app a Facebook hosted app or is it a separate site using Facebook connect or the graph or something else? Is your app in development mode, i.e. works for you and your friends only?

Comment: @Rup:I want to post status on facebook using only access_token of a user

Answer (score 0):

Here's the process I have used for one of my Facebook applications to make wall posts from a user [of my application] to one of their friends:

1. Authenticate the user via the process described in the [Authentication section of the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#authenticating-users-in-a-web-application)
2. Store the access_token (keyed against the Facebook user ID) returned after your call to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
3. When you need to post to the wall of one of the user's friends, lookup the access_token you stored in Step 2 above and call the Graph API (as described in the "Publishing" sub-section of the [Post section of the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post)) with it.

**Please note:** you will need to request the 'offline_access' extended permission to use the token after the user has logged out of Facebook. Also, Facebook do impose limits for the number of requests you can make per user per day. Theoretically, this should grow with your application but I've experienced problems before where this hasn't happened. You can check your current limits at:

http://www.facebook.com/business/insights/app.php?id=[app_id]&tab=allocations